# not receive activation email use django-registration-redux

Tags: python, django, django-registration

i use djanga 1.7 and python 2.7, i want to build registration use django-registration-redux but i not receive activation email.

this is part of my setting.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 3
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

this is url.py

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

and this is registration_form.py

```
    {% extends "base_2.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block title %}Registration{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <h1>Sign up</h1>
      <p>Already registered?  
        <a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">Sign in here.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form action="{% url 'registration_register' %}" 
        method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form layout='horizontal' %}

    {% buttons %}
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Sign Me Up!
      </button>
    </div>
    {% endbuttons %}
  </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

registration success but i am not receive activation email.

can you tell solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean you don't see the email in your console?

Comment: i mean i can receive link activation email in my email address. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EMAIL_BACKEND` is incorrectly set, if you want to receive an actual email in your inbox. The `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend` will only log the email to your console.

You need to [setup a new email backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#email-backends) such as an [SMTP backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#smtp-backend).

Comment: did you mean i just change with this code "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"

Comment: i try change with that code but i am getting error "[Errno 111] Connection refused" how?

Comment: No, you need to completely configure the new backend. Please read the documentation I linked to and follow the full instructions.